# In bremsstrahlung radiation, why does the electron decelerate when it is deflected by the nucleus?

Tags: particle-physics, electrons, atomic-physics, scattering

The nucleus would attract the electron so its kinetic energy should increase right? If this is the case where is the energy for the radiation coming from?

Comment: The electron interacts with the total field of the atomif its energy is lower than the MeV needed to see the nucleus,  and loses momentum if a bremsstrahlung photon is emitted. see Feynman diagrams here : https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/576828/are-photons-emitted-and-absorbed-in-a-direction-mostly-perpendicular-to-the-acce

Answer (score 4):

The electron accelerates toward the nucleus when it is inbound and decelerates when it is outbound.  If the electron does not radiate, these two cancel and the speed remains the same.  The electron is accelerated transversely by the nucleus, which can trigger photon emission.  The energy lost by to the photon is what slows down the electron.

Comment: Should add to this that without the concept of retarded fields, there would be no bremsstrahlung radiation and those no net deceleration.

Comment: @SeñorO Umm, cosmic plasmas emitted bremsstrahlung radiation long before anybody *modeled* it using the concept of retarded fields.

Comment: please note that the electron cannot interact with nucleus because of the negative orbitals around the nucleus, unless it is in the MeV energy  range. At lower energies it  will emit a brems interacting with the collective field of the whole atom, see feynman diagrams here :https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/576828/are-photons-emitted-and-absorbed-in-a-direction-mostly-perpendicular-to-the-acce

Comment: Thank you for clearing this to me

Comment: also is heat released during this process and if so how?

Comment: The photon that was released can be absorbed in the medium, turning into heat.  The incoming electron can also ionize the atoms of the medium, causing heat but not by bremsstrahlung